# Missing design file

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I was trying to save my project, but by mistake I save it on desktop and have only .cs file and Designer.cs. Is there any solution to restore [design] file and my whole project?

Comment: Isn't Designer.cs is the design?

Comment: When you open Visual Studio it should show a list of recent projects. Is your project there? Does it compile?

Comment: @Han by design i mean window with buttons labels etc. and designer .cs is like code, which VS made by itself

Comment: @mjwills It looks like this ![screenshot](https://imageshack.com/a/img922/396/oMXHR5.png).

Answer (score 2):

`designer.cs` is in fact the file you are looking for.

The problem is due to manually adding it as part of a project. Creating the form from Visual Studio actually does some extra tricks with the project file.

What you want to do is open your `csproj` in a text editor and correct it like so.

```
<Compile Include="stats.cs">
    <SubType>Form</SubType>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="stats.Designer.cs">
    <DependentUpon>stats.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

That should do it. Notice the `SubType` actually specifies that it is a Form. This is what Visual Studio looks at to figure out what kind of designer or view to display. `DependentUpon` is what allows files to nest underneath each other.

If this doesn't work for some reason, you can also create a new form and copy the contents of the designer.cs class into your new one and all of your controls should show back up. This can also help you fix your `resx` file. It's probably best to go this route at some point anyway so you can better understand how a csproj file is structured in general. There's a good chance, this won't be the only time you need to look at the XML.